# Issue with many-to-many query with linq to entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got a table

**Application**

```
ApplicationID,
NAme
```

**ApplicationSteps**

```
AplicationStepID,
AplicationID,
StepID
```

**ApplicationStepCriterias**

```
ApplicationStepID,
CriteriaID
```

So I've got one `SelectedCriteriaID` - a user choose from a dropdown one criteria and he wants all the applications which has this `SelectedCriteriaID` in the table `ApplicationStepCriterias`

I tried

```
 var ds = context.Applications
                   .Where(a => a.ApplicationSteps
                                  .Select(x=>x.ApplicationStepCriterias
                                                 .Select(t=>t.CriteriaId))
                                  .Contains(SelectesdCriteria));
```

But as I have as result `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` I cannot use Contains 
Just I get a list of all the `CriteriaId`s for each `ApplicationStep`(also a sequence).  Just I cannot think of  way to get in one list all the `CriteriId`s.

Comment: `.Where(blah).ToList().Contains` or just put your SelectesdCriteria in the where. `where(x=>x.ApplicationStepCriterias.Select(t=>t.CriteriaId) & SelectesdCriteria)`

Comment: `context.Applications.Where(a=>a.ApplicationSteps.Any(as=>as.ApplicationStepCriterias.Any(asc=>asc.CriteriaID==SelectedCriteriaID )))`

Answer (score 2):

First, let me try to get the names right. This is not a pure many-to-many association, because the junction class is part of the class model. It is what I unofficially call a *1-n-1* association. So you have

```
Application -< ApplicationSteps >- ApplicationStepCriterias
```

I'd strongly recommend to use singular names for your classes ...

```
Application -< ApplicationStep >- ApplicationStepCriterion
```

... so you can use plural for collection property names without getting confused.

If I'm right so far, you query should be

```
context.Applications
       .Where(a => a.ApplicationSteps
                    .Any(x => selectedCriteria
                              .Contains(x.ApplicationStepCriterion.CriteriaId));
```

(and I'd also prefer *CriterionId*, probably referring to a *Criterion* class)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
var applicationStepIds = context.ApplicationStepCriterias
                                  .Where(i => i.CriteriaID == selectedCriteria)
                                  .Select(i => i.ApplicationStepID)
                                  .Distinct();

var applicationIds = context.ApplicationSteps
                                  .Where(i => applicationStepIds.Contains(i.AplicationStepID))
                                  .Select(i => i.AplicationID)
                                  .Distinct();

var result = context.Applications.Where(i => applicationIds.Contains(i.ApplicationId));
```